# Is it possible to change the input shape of a tensorflow pretrained model?

Tags: tensorflow, transfer-learning

I have a Tensorflow pre-trained model for Image Segmentation that receives 6 bands as input, I would like to change the input size of the model to receive 4 bands so I can retrain with my own dataset, but still not able to do it, no sure if this is even possible?

I tried getting the input node by name and change it using `import_graph_def` with no success, seems like it is asking to respect the dimensions when trying to substitute.

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
tf_new_input = tf.placeholder(shape=(4, 256, 256), dtype='float32', name='new_input')
tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, input_map={"ImageInputLayer": tf_new_input})
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 4 and 6 for 'import/ImageInputLayer_Sub' (op: 'Sub') with input shapes: [4,256,256], [6,256,256]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert your 4 channel placeholder input to 6 channel input and also the input image shape should be the same as your 6 channel model expects. You may use any operation but `conv2d` is an easy operation to perform before you feed it to your existing model. This is how you do it.

```
with tf.Graph().as_default() as old_graph:
  # You have to load your 6 channel input graph here
  saver.restore(tf.get_default_session(), <<save_path>>)
  # Assuming that input node is named as 'input_node' and 
  # final node is named as 'softmax_node'

with tf.Graph().as_default() as new_graph:
  tf_new_input = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 256, 256, 4), dtype='float32')

  # Map 4 channeled input to 6 channel and 
  # image input shape should be same as expected by old model.
  new_node = tf.nn.conv2d(tf_new_input, (3, 3, 4, 6), strides=1, padding='SAME')

  # If you want to obtain output node so that you can further perform operations.
  softmax_node = tf.import_graph_def(old_graph, input_map={'input_node:0': new_node}, 
                                     return_elements=['softmax_node:0'])
```

Comment: Hi!, thanks for your help it did work!!. Sharing the code here:

Comment: Hi!, thanks for your help it did work!!. Abusing a bit of your kindness I would like to understand something, the convolution filter to change input shape is initialized randomly, so it means that this kernel has to be enhanced as well as part of the training process right? Anyway I had to loose something since my data is lack of information (channels), am I right? At least this is better that training from scratch the complete model.

Comment: Yes, adding a layer over there of conv2d will have to be trained from scratch. While you are fine-tuning the network with extra layers at the end, even the first layer will have to undergo training.

Comment: If my answer has helped you, please can you accept and upvote my answer. It will encourage me to answer more questions in future.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help again!!

Answer (score -1):

**user1190882** responded this question very well. Just using this section to post the code for future reference, I had to make a small change by creating the filter in a separate variable since I was getting an error : Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 1 for 'Conv2D' . Also I made a small change since the input format of my model is "Channels First", I added data_format flag.

```
with tf.Graph().as_default() as new_graph:

tf_new_input = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 4, 256, 256), dtype='float32')
# Creating separate variable for filter  
filterc = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 4, 6]))
new_node = tf.nn.conv2d(tf_new_input, filterc, strides=1, padding='SAME',  data_format='NCHW')
tf.import_graph_def(old_graph, input_map={'ImageInputLayer': new_node})
```